# How do I rename an EXE file and configuration from the release folder in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, rename, solution

I have a solution with `"Name1"`. When I do a build, I get `"Name1.exe"` and `"Name1.exe.config"` in the `bin` folder.

Now I want to make some changes in this application and get `"Name2.exe"` and `"Name2.exe.config"`.

I renamed the project and solution, but when I do a build I still have "Name1.exe".

How can I get another name for my EXE file?

Comment: Sounds to me you already got another name but just forgot to use Build + Clean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Assuming you work in Visual Studio: Go to project properties (menu *Debug* → <name of your project>). Go to the first section, "Application", and there will be a field, "Assembly name". Change it to whatever you want.